# OpenShift: External Access using NodePort

Tags: linux, devops, openshift-origin

I am trying Openshift v3 with a single master with a single node setup.
I installed the examples/sample-app for ruby hello openshift and the pods and service is up. When I try to  use NodePort or LoadBalancer options for enabling external access to this app's frontend, I keep getting as below :

```
[root@openshift-master~]# curl openshift-node.tidalsoft:31597
curl: (7) Failed connect to openshift-node.tidalsoft:31597; No route to host

[root@openshift-master~]# oc describe service frontend
Name:   frontend
Namespace:  test
Labels: template=application-template-stibuild
Selector:   name=frontend
Type:   NodePort
IP: 172.30.252.16
Port:   web 5432/TCP
NodePort:   web 31597/TCP
Endpoints:  10.1.0.10:8080,10.1.0.13:8080
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

when I check the rules on node :

```
[root@openshift-node~]# iptables -t nat -L | grep 31597
REDIRECT   tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* test/frontend:web */ tcp dpt:31597 redir ports 39433
DNAT       tcp  --  anywhere             anywhere             /* test/frontend:web */ tcp dpt:31597 to:10.88.102.48:39433
```

Hence I added rules to allow the redirect port 39433

```
[root@openshift-node~]# iptables -I OS_FIREWALL_ALLOW -p tcp -m tcp --dport 39433 -j ACCEPT
```

After adding this rule, external access starts working. I am now confused...is this something that's needed for external access or am I missing any config here?

Any suggestions will be great.

Answer (score 0):

For enabling external (out of cluster) access to some service it is better to use native openshift feature - [route](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/architecture/core_concepts/routes.html).

Here is also information from openshift docs about required steps for [adding route support to your openshift cluster](https://docs.openshift.org/latest/install_config/install/deploy_router.html) .

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in the Ansible installer and there is also a known issue with OpenShift SDN (which overrides the inbound rules).  Both are slated to be resolved.